# Can Field lines touch?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, vector-fields

A doubt about field lines
Can electric field lines TOUCH somewhere before infinity? I have learnt that it cannot intersect but can it be like $x$-axis for $y=x^3$ since at zero the direction of fields are the same.

Comment: Can field lines touch what? Each other? A source? What?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/214364/2451 and links therein.