# Can magnetic field lines touch each other in a current carrying circular loop?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current, vector-fields

I have a very good/dumb doubt about current carrying circular loop
since we are told that as we reach the centre of the loop the arcs of the bigger circles appear as straight lines, but if we make the diagram ourselves at some point they would touch each other but not intersect. this confuses me a lot, can anyone plz help me

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/705816/2451 and links therein.