# Electric field lines intersection with common tangent

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, vector-fields

We say that electric field lines do not intersect, because that cannot be two directions of electric field. Then can electric field line intersect in the way shown below?
[image: image showing electric field lines interesting]

This image shows that two electric field lines intersect at a point P. But here the tangents are along the same direction, so there will exist a unique direction of electric field. Hence can we say that such intersection is possible?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can field lines intersect in the way shown above?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/214364/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0):

No, they cannot.  Given an electric field $\mathbf E(\mathbf r)$, electric field lines are integral curves of the electric field, which are curves$^\dagger$ $\mathbf r:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R^3$ which obey the equation
$$\mathbf r'(\lambda) = \mathbf E\big(\mathbf r(\lambda)\big)$$

This is a first-order system of ODE's, which means$^\ddagger$ that as long as $\mathbf E$ is a well-behaved vector field, the solution $\mathbf r(\lambda)$ is uniquely determined by choosing an initial condition $\mathbf r(0)$.  In other words, given some arbitrary point $\mathbf r_0$, there is one and only one integral curve $\mathbf r(\lambda)$ which passes through $\mathbf r_0$.

---

$^\dagger$Strictly speaking, if the vector field includes singularities (e.g. point charges) the domain of some integral curves may not be all of $\mathbb R$, but we will ignore that technical point.

$^\ddagger$See the [Picard-Lindelof theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem).