# Can such a field line exist between two positive charges?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law, vector-fields

I am aware of the usual diagram of field lines between two positive charges.
My question is that is such a field line  wrong, if so why?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/214364/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that the answer below was based on a careless inspection of your diagram. I hadn't appreciated that the field lines touch with common tangents at the junction. The lines *don't* merge into one, but a more sophisticated argument is needed: see "This question has answers here" (above).

What you have drawn is wrong. There is, on your diagram, a point (P, say) where field lines from the two charges seem to merge. At P the field direction is ambiguous: it seems to have three directions.

This is unphysical. At any point, the field is the resultant of fields due to individual sources. There is therefore only a single field direction at any point. This implies that field lines never cross or meet.

Comment: Just want to confirm which of the two answers given in the question is correct. I think the accepted answer makes sense but then there is another answer that is saying something else but I am not quite able to understand  that answer. So, is the first person correct or the second one?

Comment: The top answer to "Intersection of electric field lines..." (the question you are being referred to) is, I suspect, the correct one, but there's not enough detail for me to follow it properly.

Comment: I presume that top answer here means the accepted one?

Comment: I'm so sorry: I meant the answer at the top, NOT the accepted one.

Comment: Thank you. The accepted answer comes at the top when I open that question hence I asked. You are talking about the one by doomsday. Ok. Thank you so much!